# Flutter border radius TabBar indicator

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

in `Flutter` how can i draw border radius tab indicator like with below image?

[image]

below code can only draw circle indicator which i found in `github`.

```
TabBar(
  isScrollable: true,
  controller: _tabController,
  labelColor: Colors.black,
  tabs: <Widget>[
    Tab(
      text: 'DOTTED',
    ),
    Tab(
      text: 'Tab',
    ),
    Tab(
      text: 'INDICATOR',
    ),
  ],
  indicator: DotIndicator(
    indicatorColor: Colors.black,
    radius: 3,
  ),
  indicatorWeight: 2 * kDefaultDotIndicatorRadius,
),
```

library:

```
const kDefaultDotIndicatorRadius = 3.0;

class DotTabIndicator extends Decoration {
  const DotTabIndicator({this.indicatorColor, this.radius = kDefaultDotIndicatorRadius});

  final Color indicatorColor;
  final double radius;

  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([onChanged]) {
    return _DotPainter(this, onChanged);
  }
}

class _DotPainter extends BoxPainter {
  _DotPainter(this.decoration, VoidCallback onChanged) : super(onChanged);

  final DotTabIndicator decoration;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    final center = configuration.size.center(offset);
    final dy = configuration.size.height;

    final newOffset = Offset(center.dx, dy - 8);

    final paint = Paint();
    paint.color = decoration.indicatorColor;
    paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    canvas.drawCircle(newOffset, decoration.radius, paint);
  }
}
```

Comment: where is any `DotTabIndicator` constructor called?

Comment: @pskink this code is sample of another library which that's make dot tab indicator

Comment: and instead of another library why dont you use [ShapeDecoration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ShapeDecoration-class.html)?

Comment: @pskink i don't know how can i draw this shape for tab indicator

Comment: `indicator: ShapeDecoration(...)`

Comment: @pskink are you sure this is what i want need to have? how about `child`?

Comment: yes, I am sure.

Comment: @pskink could you please give me sample code how can i do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check this out

```
class CustomIndicator extends StatelessWidget {

  var radius = Radius.circular(10);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Custom Indicator"),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: <Widget>[
              Tab(
                text: "Hello",
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "Megan",
              ),
            ],
            indicator: ShapeDecoration(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topRight: radius, topLeft: radius)),
              color: Colors.red
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Hello"),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text("Hi"),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: i want to have tab indicator not tab decoration :)

Comment: That is the indicator in red

Comment: @DolDurma Check it out now

Comment: i'm so sorry this is what i need to have `https://imgur.com/a/tLHXdWk` because of myself mistake i accepted and upvoted you post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61017114/flutter-custom-tab-indicator-under-tabs

Comment: Is there any way to set the indicator' s height at the same time? I found [this](https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-custom-tab-indicator-for-tabbar-d72bbc6c9d0c), but it' s too long.